# Populating a Html.Listbox with all ASP.NET users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a page where a listbox will contain all my ASP.NET users.

However I'm having a lot of problems attempting to make the Html.Listbox accept the list of users.

I have tried doing this:

```
<%: Html.ListBox("Membershipusers", Membership.GetAllUsers())%>
```

and a zillion other approaches that is similar to this. I also have a method on my controller that looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult getAllMembershipUsers()
    {
        MembershipUserCollection membershipusers = new MembershipUserCollection();

        membershipusers = Membership.GetAllUsers();

        return View(membershipusers);
    }
```

It seems like it is able to create the list of users, but I still don't know how to show that list in my listbox.

Hope somebody can help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a view model? Have you tried this approach?

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and then a controller which will populate this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();
    var model = new UsersViewModel
    {
        AvailableUsers = users.Select(u => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = u.UserName,
            Text = u.UserName
        })
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view to the view model

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UsersViewModel>" %>
...
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedUsers, Model.AvailableUsers) %>
```

Comment: I have used the approach you suggested. it seems to work fine except that i get this error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel'.

Comment: @AronChan, the error message seems pretty self explanatory. Your view is strongly typed to `List<User>` and you are passing a `UsersViewModel` to it. So you need to adapt your view model.

Comment: care to elaborate a bit Darin? not entirely sure how i should change my model

Comment: @AronChan, it's very hard to elaborate on how you should change your model without me knowing how your model currently looks like. But you could add a property on the view model that is of type `List<User>` that will contain the data that you currently use as model.

Comment: Hi.. since i changed so much in my way of doing this i created a new question here on stack in order to make the topic reflect what i am actually trying to achieve. it can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147129/selectlist-wont-accept-my-selectlistitem-object