# SelectList wont accept my SelectListItem object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Im trying to populate my Html.Listbox with all the users of my ASP.NET user database.

I have created a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models
{
public class UsersViewModel
    {
        MembershipUserCollection membershipuserscollection { get; set; }
        public List<MembershipUser> membershipuserslist { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> AvailableUsers { get; set; }

        public UsersViewModel()
        {
            availableUsers = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }  
    }
}
```

And a Actionresult that looks like this:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();

        UsersViewModel model = new UsersViewModel();

        foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
        {
            SelectListItem selectuser = new SelectListItem();

            selectuser.Text = user.UserName;
            selectuser.Value = user.UserName;

            model.AvailableUsers.Add(selectuser);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

On my view i try to populate the list like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel>" %>


<%= Html.ListBox("AvailableUsers", Model.AvailableUsers)%>
```

When i run the code i get the follow error:

CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel' because 'SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AvailableUsers is not initialized, you can do this in the constructor of your ViewModel, for example.

```
public class UsersViewModel
     {
     public UsersViewModel {
         AvailableUsers = new List<SelectListItem>();
     }
     MembershipUserCollection membershipuserscollection { get; set; }
     public List<MembershipUser> membershipuserslist { get; set; }
     public List<SelectListItem> AvailableUsers { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: It was correct that i forgot to make a constructor. unfortunately that just proved a new problem for me xD im starting to rip out my hair on this one.

CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'availableUsers' and no extension method 'availableUsers' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

not sure if this makes any sense to you?

Comment: Hmmm, where does this happen ? Where does that IEnmerable<UsersViewModel> come from, is that your view's model ?

Comment: Somehow it seems that it regards my ViewModel object as an Enumerable now. i cant access any of the lists on it from my view :S

Comment: IEnumerable<UsersViewModel> is the viewmodel. it should contain the list of users that i used my controller to fill with user objects

Comment: hmmm, update your question and put your entire view code, please. EDIT : UsersViewModel is not IEnumerable. It must be a single instance CONTAINING lists, no ?

Comment: i changed the view to accept the model now. problem solved. however i still get this error when i try to run the code:


CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel' because 'SkyLearn.Areas.Users.Models.UsersViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Once again, put your entire view's code would make things easier. What I guess it that you try to enumerate on a single UsersViewModel. You can make a foreach on Model.membershipuserslist, for example. Not on Model.

Comment: i updated the question up top a bit. rest of my views code is only design related and kind of irrelevant :)

Comment: Indeed not irrelevant. it was not the foreach on my controller it was an autogenerated forach on my view that caused me trouble. Thank you alot for your help mate. it all works now :D

Comment: we did it ;) Saved your hair !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same name as the first argument of the ListBox helper as a property on your view model (`AvailableUsers`). That's not correct. The first argument should represent a property on your view model that will be used to bind the selected values back. In the case of a ListBox helper, this should be a collection because the user can select multiple values. In the case of a DropDownList helper this should be a simple scalar property. The second argument (in both cases) represents a collection of `SelectListItem` which will be used to render the available options.

So let's take an example of how you could improve your view model:

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public string[] SelectedUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and then the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();
    var model = new UsersViewModel
    {
        AvailableUsers = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.UserName,
            Text = x.UserName
        })
    };
    return View(model); 
}
```

and finally the view:

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UsersViewModel>" 
%>

<%= Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedUsers, Model.AvailableUsers) %>
```

You will notice that I have gotten rid of the `membershipuserscollection` and the `membershipuserslist` properties that you had initially in your view model which accomplish no purpose in this example. The first one is private and the second one is a collection of a domain model (`MembershipUser`) so it has absolutely no place in a view model.

Comment: I dont have much experience in coding mvc3 and i must say i really cannot wrap my head arround your code example. any chance you could write some comments in the code to tell me exactly what happens step by step? obviously i want to do it the right way. but its important for me to understand what i am doing instead of just copy pasta :)